# How to update a column using values from another table in Amazon Redshift

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have 2 tables:

Table 'A':

```
Old_eid    new_eid
<null>     <null>
a          <null>
b          <null>
c          <null>
```

Table 'B':

```
eid1    eid2
a         d
b         e
c         f
```

I would like to update Table 'A' as follows:

```
Old_eid    new_eid
<null>     <null>
a             d
b             e
c             f
```

I came up with the following query but it gives me an error:

```
UPDATE A
   SET new_eid = (SELECT eid2
                  FROM A a
                    JOIN B b ON a.old_eid = b.eid1)
WHERE old_eid IS NOT NULL
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
UPDATE A
       SET new_eid = (SELECT eid2
                      FROM A a
                        JOIN B b ON a.old_eid = b.eid1)
    WHERE old_eid IS NOT NULL

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Invalid Query: 
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Invalid Query: 
  code:      8001
  context:   single-row subquery returns more than one row
  query:     967978
  location:  8.cpp:78
  process:   padbmaster [pid=15160]
  -----------------------------------------------;

Execution time: 0.35s
1 statement failed.
```

I can understand the error because it is resulting in more than one rows, but I'm not sure how to get what I want.

How do I replace these values? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redshift table update with join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785868/redshift-table-update-with-join)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do this using:

```
UPDATE A
   SET new_eid = eid2
FROM B cm 
WHERE cm.eid1= old_eid
and old_eidIS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Amazon RedShift but in SQL, this code:

```
(SELECT eid2 FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.old_eid = b.eid1)
```

will return all rows on A joined to B for every row to be updated.

You should use something like:

```
UPDATE A
   SET new_eid = (SELECT eid2
                  FROM B b WHERE A.old_eid = b.eid1)
WHERE old_eid IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar snippet below:

```
update test1 set col2=test2.col2
from test2 
join test1 cat 
on test2.col1=cat.col1;
```