# Update table based on self table lookup in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the below table,

```
id   email   mgr_email   mgr_id
-------------------------------
1    email1   email2    
2    email2   email3
3    email3   email4
```

I want to populate the column mgr_id from id column by matching mgr_email with email, just like below:

```
id   email   mgr_email   mgr_id
-------------------------------
1    email1   email2      2
2    email2   email3      3
3    email3   email4
```

The below query gets me the required result in postgres:

```
update mytable t1 set mgr_id=t2.id from mytable t2 where t1.mgr_email=t2.email
```

But when I try in redshift it gives me the below error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "t1"
LINE 1: update mytable t1 set mgr_id=t2.id from mytable t2 where t1.mg...
                       ^
```

How do I do this in redshift ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redshift table update with join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785868/redshift-table-update-with-join)

Comment: Not duplicate, I am talking about same table not different table

Comment: Do **not** tag Redshift questions with `postgresql`. Although they share some common roots they are very different databases. Your query works just fine in Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is not working in redshift.

Comment: That's precisely the reason you should not tag questions for Redshift with Postgres

Comment: Okay, lets leave tagging aside. I want the same kinda query that works in redshift.

Comment: That question shows you the syntax on how to *join* tables in an *update* command which is precisely what you are doing. Just use that syntax to join your table with itself. That's why it is a duplicate.

Comment: What's the use of join if you are looking up for data in the same table? btw replacing other table with same table doesn't work. Gives table name "mytable" specified more than once error. I am seeing if I can do it without join just like the query I am using in postgresql.

Comment: Redshift doesn't support table alias in delete, update queries.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit ugly but you really have to write the subquery with self-join and only then update the table from it:

```
update mytable
set mgr_id=t.id
from (
    select t1.email,t2.id
    from mytable t1 
    join mytable t2
    on t1.mgr_email=t2.email
) t
where mytable.email=t1.email;
```

as said in comments, it's the particular case of more generic update from table syntax

Answer (score 1):

Use sub query for self join:

Try this:

```
update mytable 
    set mgr_id=t2.id 
    from (select id, email from mytable) t2 
    where mytable.mgr_email=t2.email
```