# UPDATE with join referencing same table - Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Assume I have a table named tab. Tab has a field called "version". Version is sequential.

In Redshift, I would like to update rows in Tab with the value from a previous row. Please tell me how to do this. Essentially:

```
UPDATE tab
    SET tab.fieldA = tabPrior.fieldA
    FROM tab tabPrior
    WHERE tab.version = tabPrior.version + 1;
```

I would love to use a JOIN, but this does not seem to work in Redshift.

Comment: I would expect your code to work.

Comment: Please report the error from such an update query.

Comment: A `FROM` in an `UPDATE` is effectively the same as a `JOIN`. By the way, `UPDATE` statements in Amazon Redshift are quite inefficient because previous versions of a row are marked as deleted and new rows are added to the end of the storage space. Run a `VACUUM` afterwards to reclaim disk space and make the table more efficient for querying.

Comment: Have you tried the code you gave an example? If so and this didn't work, what was the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update table based on self table lookup in redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769936/update-table-based-on-self-table-lookup-in-redshift)

Comment: this is a duplicate question, I've referenced you to the original answer

Answer (score 0):

To Update with a JOIN statement you are better off writing it in a subquery.

```
UPDATE table 
SET 
 col1 = TT.col1
 col2 = TT.col2
FROM (SELECT T1.id, T1.col1, T2.col2 
     FROM T1 
     JOIN T2 ON T1. id ON T2. id) AS TT
WHERE table.id = TT.id
```

Also, I noticed that your syntax is the SET is not correct:

```
SET fieldA = tabPrior.fieldA
```

Redshift does not allow for you to pass the table when selecting the column since it goes under the assumption that you are updating 1 table at a time.

> SET column = One or more columns that you want to modify. Columns that
> aren't listed retain their current values. **Do not include the table
> name in the specification of a target column. For example, UPDATE tab
> SET tab.col = 1 is invalid.**

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UPDATE.html