# update + case + join statement in Redshift

Tags: sql, sql-update, case, amazon-redshift

I have this code from SQL Server that I have to implement in Redshift.

```
update t1 set some_flag = (case when b.some_value is null then false else true end)
from t1 a
left join t2 b on a.code = b.code;
```

I get an error in Redshift that says:

```
 Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate
```

How can I amend the above to make it work in Redshift? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update table based on self table lookup in redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769936/update-table-based-on-self-table-lookup-in-redshift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must fully qualify the table name with column instead of alias. Redshift does not support table alias in update command i guess.

```
update merge_demo1
set lastname = (case when merge_demo1.lastname = merge_demo1.lastname then merge_demo1.lastname else merge_demo2.lastname end)
from merge_demo2
where merge_demo1.id = merge_demo2.id;
```

Comment: Does this create a left or an inner join?

Comment: It is inner join

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the reference in the `from` clause:

```
update t1
    set some_flag = (case when b.some_value is null then false else true end)
from t2 b 
where t1.code = b.code;
```

Postgres (and Postgres-derived databases) allow a `FROM` clause for `UPDATE`.  However, the table references are *in addition to* the referenced table in the `UPDATE`.  This differs from SQL Server, where the table reference in the `UPDATE` is assumed to come from the `FROM` clause if possible -- even ignoring the alias if necessary.

You should be able to simplify this to:

```
update t1
    set some_flag = (b.some_value is not null);
from t2 b 
where t1.code = b.code;
```

Comment: Sorry, no go. Redshift says 'relation "a" does not exist'

Comment: I tried to use "t1 a" but I guess you can't use an alias in the update context

Comment: @ChuckPedro . . . That should be `t1`.  I would expect an alias to work, but Redshift may not support it.