# How to update redshift table (t1) from another table (t2)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-update, amazon-redshift

I've a redshift table:

table t1 with cols -> a,b,c,d 
table t2 with cols -> a,c,d

I need to update c,d values where t1.a = t2.a

t1 can have multiple rows with same a while t2 will have a single row for each a (a is unique in t2). Can I understand how can I update the values of t1.c, t1.d using t2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redshift table update with join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785868/redshift-table-update-with-join)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably use something like:

```sql
UPDATE t1
SET t1.c = t2.c,
    t1.d = t2.d
FROM t2
WHERE t1.a = t2.a
```

See also: [Examples of UPDATE statements - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Examples_of_UPDATE_statements.html)
The table mentioned after `UPDATE` acts like it was included in the `FROM` and the extra tables can be added via the `FROM`, with joining via the `WHERE`.